# A mass is oscillating on the end of a spring. The distance, y, of the mass from its equilibrium point is given by the formula

Tags: calculus, physics

A mass is oscillating on the end of a spring. The distance, y, of the mass from its equilibrium point is given by the formula 
$$y=7z\cos(12π\omega t)$$

where y is in centimeters, t is time in seconds, and z and $\omega$ are positive constants.
(b) How many oscillations are completed in 1 second?

I don't actually understand this problem. Could someone help me to explain the question and give me some helps about solving the question.

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: What is the period of the function $y=\cos(12\pi\omega t)?$

Answer (score 1):

The frequency of oscillation is:
$$\nu=\dfrac{\Omega}{2\pi}$$
$$\Omega=12\pi\omega$$
So: 
$$\nu=6\omega$$ which ise the frequency of oscillation in $Hz$. This means you have $6\omega$ oscillations every second

Answer (score 0):

One oscillation correspond to the change of $2\pi$ of the argument of the cosine function. So if we start at $t=0$, at time $t=T$, where $T$ is the period of the oscillation, the argument of the cosine changed by $2\pi$. $$12\pi\omega T-12\pi\omega 0=2\pi$$ This yields the period of the oscillation as $$T=\frac{1}{6\omega}$$ Now if you know the period, you can simply calculate how many of those are in one second.